# Set tool tip for NSComboBox items

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, tooltip, nscombobox

How can i show tool tip for `NSComboBox` items while hovering mouse as they are too long to be displayed?. I have tried by setting `allow expansion tool tip`  but it is not showing. For TableView and text filed this is working. So what can i do?

Comment: I know it's very old question, but I am also facing the same problem. Please update the answer if you know it now?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, NSComboBox doesn't support this. I've just sent radar://42151561 to the AppKit team about this very issue.

Reporting issues at bugreport.apple.com is the best way to make Apple engineers aware of bugs that you notice, and earlier is always better. :-)